# Error unexpected token in stored procedure Advantage Database SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, advantage-database-server

I have A stored procedure that is giving me an unexpected Token; ORDER expecting semicolon when I have this statement near the end when I try to execute it.

**select year from #temp where year is not null ORDER BY year DESC;**

if I remove the **ORDER BY year DESC;** the procedure works correctly.

I've tried every way possible to sort the resulting table in descending order.  I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm sure its something simple.  TIA.

// --------- full stored procedure ------ //

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetYearForExhaustCatalog
   ( 
      CatCodeString Memo,
      Year CHAR ( 4 ) OUTPUT
   ) 
BEGIN 
/*

  EXECUTE PROCEDURE GetYearForExhaustCatalog('(e.catalogcode= ''2182'')');

  EXECUTE PROCEDURE GetYearForExhaustCatalog('');


*/  

DECLARE @CatCodeString string;
DECLARE @SQL string;

@CatCodeString = (SELECT CatCodeString FROM __input);

if @CatCodeString IS NULL or @CatCodeString = '' then
  select e2.year,
  (SELECT top 1 e2.year
  FROM  eenginecatalog e LEFT JOIN exhaustengine e2 ON e2.app_no=e.app_no)
  as year
  into #temp
  from Exhaustengine e2;
  select year from #temp where year is not null
  GROUP BY  year
  ORDER BY  year DESC;
else
  @SQL = 
    'select e2.year, '+ 
    '(SELECT top 1 e2.year '+
    'FROM  eenginecatalog e LEFT JOIN exhaustengine e2 ON e2.app_no=e.app_no and '+
       @CatCodeString +' ) '+ 
    'as year '+
    'into #temp '+
    'from Exhaustengine e2; '+
    'select year from #temp where year is not null '+
    'GROUP BY  year '+
    'ORDER BY  year DESC ';
  execute immediate @SQL;
end;

insert into __output
  select year from #temp where year is not null ORDER BY year;
  drop table #temp;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ADS does not like the `ORDER BY` clause when inserting into the special `__output` table.

This does not work as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(Year INTEGER OUTPUT) 
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE #tmp ("Year" INTEGER);

INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2019);
INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2017);
INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2018);

INSERT INTO
  __output
SELECT
  "Year"
FROM #tmp
ORDER BY
  "Year";

DROP TABLE #tmp;

END;
```

It fails with the same error message you got:

```
poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2117;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Unexpected token: ORDER -- Expecting semicolon. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 269 (line: 15 column: 1)
```

As a workaround you can create another temporary table that has the result sorted:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(Year INTEGER OUTPUT) 
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE #tmp ("Year" INTEGER);

INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2019);
INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2017);
INSERT INTO #tmp ("Year") VALUES (2018);

SELECT
  *
INTO #sorted
FROM #tmp
ORDER BY
  "Year"
;

INSERT INTO
  __output
SELECT
  "Year"
FROM #sorted;

DROP TABLE #sorted;
DROP TABLE #tmp;

END;
```

This works without errors and the data is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The __output table is not the culprit. In SQL standard, ORDER BY is not allowed in sub-queries in general. The reason is that sorting a set of rows should have no effect during the internal resolution of a query. It is only useful in the final result. In pure SQL sense, the only action that guarantees the result is sorted is the ORDER BY on the final result.

If you follow this logic, the possible alternative is not to try to put the data into the __output table in sorted order but to make final output sorted with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (EXECUTE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(inParam)) t ORDER BY t.year
```